# Jenkins display chart on dashboard

Tags: charts, jenkins, dashboard, pdepend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jenkins - add chart to the job interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230542/jenkins-add-chart-to-the-job-interface)

The first question is - how can I add the pdepend chart to the Jenkins' dashboard (under the project's title) ?

And the second question (I couldn't submit the post with the first one only - not enough text :P) - how do I start using phpmd? I mean, well..I type in the CLI: phpmd folder/ text naming. And what it does? Should it create some report file and check for the naming build-in conventions in the given location? I couldn't find anything about that in documentations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the easiest way would be to build your own dashboard using [Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) plugin. You can add different portlets to your new dashboard with all sort of content in it.

Otherwise you can use a [Sectioned View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sectioned+View+Plugin) plugin, which have a similar goal, but different approach to building dashboards.