# Jenkins - add chart to the job interface

Tags: php, jenkins

How can I add the pdepend chart to the Jenkins job interface (under the project's title)? Is it actually possible to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. The Jenkins description allows for images to be added.

Some time ago you could use `embed` but that was removed when XSS protection was added but:

Assuming your charts are under `build/pdepend/*` paste the following two lines in the description:

```
<img type="image/svg+xml" height="300" src="ws/build/pdepend/overview-pyramid.svg" width="500"></img>
<img type="image/svg+xml" height="300" src="ws/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg" width="500"></img>
```

By using a relative path you don't need to change the path if you rename the project or move the server.

Comment: Any idea how it works when using an aws ec2 slave instance ?

Answer (score 7):

Even after using the solution given by [edorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285578/edorian) it doesn't worked for me.

After doing some R&D i observed that it was a bug in Jenkins

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22028

and resolved in 1.564 or newer.

To resolve this all you have to do is.. go to  Manage Jenkins> Configure Global Security > and select the markup formatter as RAW HTML.

Comment: In Jenkins ver. 1.554.3, you'll need to select "Safe HTML" from the Markup Formatter dropdown box. It probably got renamed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this  may help to those who are searching a way to do this. 
First, my project is a test project, in which one of my test steps, writes a file with the result I want to measure along time,so I have a csv file. Then I integrated a [highchart.js](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart) script, in the project description, with the csv values. So, this way I have a chart with the values of all jobs in one place, and look like this:

[image: Jenkins chart screenshot]

Note: to do this, you have to install the 'anything-goes-formatter' plugin, which I think has security risks.
I hope this will be helpful to someone.